# One line push item array and return item

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this:

```
  getReadableStream() {
    const readableStream = new Readable({
      read(size) {
        return false;
      }
    });
    this.readableStreams.push(readableStream);
    return readableStream;
  }
```

however it would be nice if I could push to the array and return the item in the same call, I am looking for this:

```
 getReadableStream() {
    return this.readableStreams.push(new Readable({
      read(size) {
        return false;
      }
    }));
  }
```

but of course `Array.prototype.push` doesn't return the item that was pushed. Any way to do this with JavaScript? Ideally I don't want to create a new array, keep the original array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in one line you could use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
return this.readableStreams.push(readableStream), readableStream;
```

Answer (score 1):

An ugly solution would be to override the Arrays prototype:

```
Array.prototype.pushAndReturn = function(el){
  this.push(el);
  return el;
};
```

So you can do

```
return readableStreams.pushAndReturn(new Readable())
```

---

Alternatively just create a helper:

```
const push = (arr, el) => arr.push(el) && el;
```

So you can do:

```
return push(readableStreams, new Readable())
```

Comment: yeah, it's such a shame that this doesn't exist natively

Comment: @alexander i dont think so. There is no real usecase for this